# How to format multiple authors separated by \and?

Tags: titles

I have a document class for theses which, up until now, only accepted one author name. But now, due to a change in the university's regulation, the document will have to accept more than one author name.

Currently, I am using the standard `\author{}` command to get the author name . My question is: how can I get the separate author names in order to apply the correct formatting to them? Are there different variable names for each one? I know multiple authors are separated by `\and` and, after I am able to get each author name, I would like to put them one below the other, in a centered position (just like the example below, but with each additional author name below the previous one).

Here I have the code of my `\maketitle` command, which is the only one that uses the author names. In the image below, I show the resulting title page.

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\clearpage % clears pages just to be sure
\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no numbering
\begin{center} %text is centered
\textbf{ % and bold
\MakeUppercase{\@institution}\\[\baselineskip] % institution name
\MakeUppercase{\@author} % author name
\vfill
\MakeUppercase{\@title}\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@subtitle}}{}{:\@subtitle}} % title and optional subtitle
\vfill
\@city\\ % city
\number\year %year
\end{center}
}
```

[image: Here's an image of how it looks now]

### Clarifying Update

I believe I wasn't clear before, but now I have additional information regarding the issue. Following the recent answer, I decided to forget about `\and` and try to separate author names with `\\` so they could each go in a separate line, but it seems that `\MakeUppercase{}` does not allow for line breaks to be inserted inside it. Any advice?

So you  see, my issue is not related to the `\and` command in itself, but rather with a way to break a string in many lines while keeping it in uppercase.

I guess an example of what I'm trying to do, but which is not working, is the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\author{Doug \\ Lou}

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{\@author}
\end{document}
```

### End result update

Just for posterity, I will add here the end result, after using the chosen solution from this post.

```
\def\and{\\} % redefine so it is compatible with other classes

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\clearpage % clears pages just to be sure
\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no numbering
\begin{center} %text is centered
\textbf{ % and bold
\MakeUppercase{\@institution}\\[\baselineskip] % institution name
\uppercase\expandafter{\@author} % uppercase author names!!
\vfill
\MakeUppercase{\@title}\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@subtitle}}{}{:\@subtitle}} % title and optional subtitle
\vfill
\@city % city
\number\year % year
\end{center}
}
```

Comment: For a more specific answer, you would have to include [a compilable MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe/3301#3301) that recreates your situation.  As it is, I cannot make your code snippet work in action, as it has too many user-defined portions.

Comment: @cslstr I just expanded my question based on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `report.cls` defines the author portion of `\maketitle` to be a tabular array, that is

```
{\large   
 \lineskip .75em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    \@author
  \end{tabular}\par}%
```

The default definition of `\and` from `latex.ltx` is used to end the `tabular` environment, add a bit of horizontal space, and then start a new `tabular` environment:

```
\def\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
```

So, when you write `\author{First \and Second}`, the result is that both names get typeset side-by-side in individual `tabular` environments.  You could just as easily write `\author{First \\ Second}` to have the two names typeset in a column (that is, in the single centered column of the first `tabular` environment).  The same could be done by redefining `\and` as `\def\and{\\}`; only through chance does simply writing `\author{First & Second}` do the same thing, as the "extra" alignment character, `&`, is interpreted as `\\` automatically.

But this last approach will only work for you if you include something along the lines of the original author portion of `\maketitle`, that defines the `tabular` array in your own `\maketitle`.

### Updated from OP Edit:

You can use `\uppercase` to do the uppercase translation in the following manner.  As noted, I suggest you use the entire structure (with `tabular`) as originally defined in `report.cls` for the author portion in your own `\maketitle`.  This keeps the original format with `\and` working, along with the other methods I mention above.

```
\documentclass{report}
\author{Doug \\ Lou}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{center}

% Suggest using the tabular in your \maketitle definition
{\large   
 \lineskip .75em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    \uppercase\expandafter{\@author}
  \end{tabular}\par}%

\end{center}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is very enlightening, but it did not solve my problem, unfortunately. I just expanded my question to see if I could clarify some things.

Comment: @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti I have updated my answer.  Also note that you must wrap any code using the `@` character in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` for it to compile correctly.

Comment: That's exact what I needed, that line with `\uppercase\expandafter` did the trick. Since I will be using this inside a `cls` file, there is no need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. I also added `\def\and{\\}` so that it would be compatible with my class style. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing only the matter that's mentioned in the "update" part of your posting: Whenever a macro -- in the present case, `\@author` -- contains one or more  `@` ("at") symbols, one has to encase it (the macro) in a pair of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\author{Doug \\ Lou}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter   % new
\noindent       % new, for more consistent formatting
\MakeUppercase{\@author}
\makeatother    % new
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I explained above, my plan is to use this code inside a `cls` file, so I will not need to encase it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. I only did that in the question so I could give the minimal working example.